# How to ensure two columns always equal the same thing

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, database-normalization

I have a table with many rows, but the name and id column always need to equal the same thing relative to each other.

Example:

```
name      id      value
'josh'     1      'blah'
'josh'     1      'foo'
'marc'     2      'bar'
'marc'     2      'boo'
```

At no time should there be a row with name 'josh' where id != 1  but the combo may be repeated many times (so it's not a primary key).

Comment: If it is a constraint, model it as a constraint. If {name,Id} is unique make it unique. (`name` appears to refer to a stronger domain, maybe `id` is even redundant, or the other way round)

Comment: I removed the tag [unique constraint]. The case looks somewhat similar, but is completely unrelated.

Comment: "always need to equal the same thing relative to each other" does not mean anything.

Comment: 1) You should never call a column id when its not the table's id. 2) Is id the person's id? Then why is there no person table holding the persons, i.e. id and name?

Answer (score 4):

This data doesn't look to be normalized.

If you can still change the table design, I'd create a separate table:

```
create table example_people (
    id int not null primary key,
    -- unique constraint fixes problem identified by philipxy
    name varchar not null unique
)
```

Then redefine your existing table to be:

```
create table example_value (
    id int not null,
    value varchar,
    constraint fk_value foreign key (id) references example_people (id)
);
```

The alternative of triggers that check the whole table generally performs fairly poorly, as it has to serialize write access.

Comment: That does not stop Josh from appearing with two different ids.

Comment: I'd like to give you the same advice that I am giving the OP: You should never call a column id when its not the table's id. That can easily lead to wrong assumptions and consequently flawed queries.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'd never call a column Id in a database I designed, but when answering a question I'll use the conventions of the person asking the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is what i would do:

1. Create a table using name and id (PK) and check name as unique
2. Create a table with value and a foreign key to the first

Comment: That does not stop Josh from appearing with two different ids.

Comment: @philipxy that is true. Branko Dimitrijevic got it right. Edited anyway

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem is the [functional dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) `id -> name`, which violates the [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

You resolve it by splitting the table into two:

```
CREATE TABLE name_table (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE value_table (
    value varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    id int NOT NULL REFERENCES name_table
);
```

You can easily "reconstruct" the original table through a JOIN, which you can wrap into a VIEW or a stored procedure (DBMS-dependent) etc.

BTW, try to figure-out better names than that! Also, consider whether adding a [surrogate key](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) to `value_table` would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

You can find bad data with

```
SELECT id, FROM your_table
GROUP BY id HAVING count(first_name)>1;
```

and a similar query with id and first_name reversed. I suppose you can UNION stuff up too. But as Laurence and Jose have said, what you should do is pull ID and Name into a separate table and use just one of them as a foreign key.

Comment: `HAVING count(first_name)>1` doesn't help. `HAVING count(DISTINCT first_name)>1` would detect *some* violations but not others and the question is how to *prevent* violations a priori.

Comment: Ahh, right, `COUNT DISTINCT`. But I think that would catch all the violations (if you also did the vice-versa query for count(id). Except for NULL, what could get missed? As far as preventing a priori, normalization…

Comment: vice-versa and NULL, that's all the "others". And yes, the answer is normalization.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, you shouldn't use id for a column that is not a primary key, it will be misleading for other teammates to understand what is going on in this database table.
- It appears that you are willing to use ( name, id ) as a key that may have multiple values,
  `( 'josh', 1) --> 'blah', 'foo'`

@Branko Dimitrijevic's answer seem to work for you, however you shouldn't make **value** a primary key, as you may have another ( name, id ) combo with the same value, e.g `( marc, 2 ) --> ( 'blah', 'foo', ... )`

So, here's SQL script I suggest

```
CREATE TABLE name_table (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE value_table (
    value_table_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    value varchar(50),
    id int NOT NULL REFERENCES name_table
);
```